# Set screen lock settings programmatically

Tags: android

On Settings -> Security -> Screen Lock there are two settings:

- Lock after screen timeout
- Power button instantly locks

Is it possible to set these values programmatically?

Where on the android source code are those parameters?

[image: gear wheel on screen lock]

[image: screen lock settings]

Comment: "On Settings -> Security -> Screen Lock there are two settings" -- on your device model, perhaps. There are tens of thousands of device models. So, for example, those settings do not show up on a Pixel 3 running Android 11, or a Pixel 5 running Android 11, or a OnePlus Nord N100, etc. "Where on the android source code are those parameters?" -- it is likely that they do not exist there.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added screenshots from Pixel 2 xl running android 11. The settings are found also on samsung s10  (custom rom based on android 9), on samsung s21 with android 11 and moto g(6) with android 9. Currently I have no other phones to try. Have you set a pin? These options are visible only if you set one. I'd expect android to allow changing these settings programmatically, at least from an app with device admin permission that is used to provision multiple phones.

Comment: First, my sincere apologies; I have now found the options you cited on the two Pixels. The Nord N100 seems to have something equivalent, under different names. "I'd expect android to allow changing these settings programmatically, at least from an app with device admin permission that is used to provision multiple phones" -- I have no idea if that is available. "Where on the android source code are those parameters?" -- you might examine the source of the AOSP Settings app, see if you can find those options, and see what they control.